# Uniqueness of Thue–Morse sequence in Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem

Tags: number-theory

[Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem) is to find two sets of numbers $A,B$ such that $\sum\limits_{a\in A}a^i=\sum\limits_{b\in B}b^i$ for $i=0,1,\cdots,k$.

A well-known set of solutions is generated by [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence). Divide $0,1,\cdots, 2^{k+1}-1$ into two sets by $t_n$ is $0$ or $1$ gives a solution of $k$.

Is this division unique for $0,1,\cdots, 2^{k+1}-1$? If yes, how to prove it? If no, is there a counterexample?